# How to negate browser behavior for rounding up/keeping unproportional pixel values?

Tags: html, css

Given the code sample:

```css
  .container {
    zoom: 1.25;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .wrapper div {
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  a
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
How can we enforce the browser to not round up some "bars", but all of them, or enforce it to keep the old values? I am not aiming for one of those scenarios, but rather consistency.

Comment: SELECT CEILING(#) AS CeilValue;

Comment: Why are you using `zoom` ? Did you read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom ? Basically they say, do not use it

Comment: @Caramba To replicate the issue. Originally the issue was reported by person using 125% zoom on windows. It has the same effect here. I am not using zoom on the website.

Comment: Don't use zoom, that is the only way

Comment: @Sebastian follow the link I've posted above. It expalins that using `1` as zoom factor is equivalent to using `100%` so it's the same. If you remove `zoom` from css you can not reproduce it anymore, right?

Comment: I'll try to explain again:
The issue happened on a page with no use of zoom. The zoom came from windows scale. Default recommended for laptops with full hd: 1.25.

I just replicated the issue using browser's zoom